# jQuery: How to switch background image which remains even after refreshing the page?

Tags: jquery

I am following the style switching method from following:
http://designshack.net/articles/css-style-switcher

It is working very good but I need to change background image as it changes the colors. So how can we change the background image which may remain the same even after refreshing the page?

They've used the cookies method in above example for stylesheets, but how can we use the same for separate image backgrounds? I am not a jQuery ninja ;)

Answer (score 0):

Using javascript, you could set and get cookies to pull image URLs to load. Without seeing where all your images are stored, I can't give you specific code, but the idea is:

```
function setCookie(c_name,value,exdays) {
    var exdate=new Date();
    exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
    var c_value=escape(value) + ((exdays==null) ? "" : "; expires="+exdate.toUTCString());
    document.cookie=c_name + "=" + c_value;
}

function getCookie(c_name) {
    var i,x,y,ARRcookies=document.cookie.split(";");
    for (i=0;i<ARRcookies.length;i++) {
        x=ARRcookies[i].substr(0,ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
        y=ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=")+1);
        x=x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
        if (x==c_name)
            return unescape(y);
    }
}
```

And then when you want to save the background url:

```
setCookie("my_bg","images/my_image1.png", 7);
```

And when you load the page:

```
$('#div_to_set_bg_of').css("background-image": "url("+getCookie("my_bg")+")");
```

Comment: The issue is probably something to do with jsfiddle handling cookies. I'd imagine there's some security reason for blocking them. If it works fine outside of fiddle, congrats! If not, send me the the code or link me to the page you're working on and I'll try to help further.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. i've put all the code into that fiddle. above plugin needed 2 stylesheets to link witn but I tried to insert them into fiddle as an internal stylesheet so may be it is not showing for the default font. But the main problem remains there: the background image and the cookies for the bg images.....Plz have a look at the fiddle and you'll understand very well..

Comment: I've added all the data in a fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/mrto2/e9bbn/16  Now the color schemes/fonts are working perfectly. When we click on blue then the font changes into blue and cookies are stored. (Default is not working in fiddle but its perfect in my PC). I've tried to add background image switch but it is giving 2 problems. 1) the cookies (here i need your help the most. If You could incorporate it into "styleswitcher.js" or just into fiddle then my life would be easier) 2) Just the background color is working and it is not picking the background image.... Regards –